# copy pivots from sheet with same name to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get only the values from each of the 9 pivot tables on each sheet in data.xlsm file to copy to the corresponding sheet name in the district file (there are currently 12 districts with the same in both workbooks). However, I am getting all the pivot tables from each sheet from data.xlsm copying over to each sheet in the district file.

Is there a way to only get the pivot tables values if the sheet names are the same in each workbook? For example, the all the pivots from Pacifa sheet in data to Pacifica sheet in distrcict.

Here is what I currently have.

```
Sub pivots()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim wbook As Workbook
    Dim strName As String
    
    
    
    'Clear Contents
    Set dbook = Workbooks("District.xlsm")
    
    For Each sht In dbook.Worksheets
        sht.Activate
        sht.Cells.Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        sht.Cells(1, 1).Select ' edit: select the first cell to cancel selection of the whole sheet
    Next sht
    
    
    'Checks for matching sheet names in both workbooks if it matches then loops over each sheet to copy and paste each pivot table to corresponding sheet without linking the source data
    Set wbook = Workbooks("data.xlsm")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    
    For Each sht In wbook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 9
            LR = dbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            sht.Activate
            sht.PivotTables("PivotTable" & i).PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
            Selection.Copy
            
        Next i
        ' Pastes values into Districts excel workbook
        For Each Ws In dbook.Worksheets
            For s = 1 To 12
                Ws.Activate
                Ws.Worksheets ("Sheet" & s)
                Ws.Range("A" & LR).Select
                Ws.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
            Next s
            
            
        Next Ws
        
    Next sht
    
    MsgBox "done!"
    
    
    'Formatting pivot tables for column adjustment
    numCol =     Workbooks("District.xlsm").Sheets("Northland").UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    
    letcol = Replace(Cells(1, numCol).Address(False, False), "1", "")
    
    Workbooks("District.xlsm").Activate
    
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:" & letcol).AutoFit
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub

'Function to check for same sheet name
Function SheetExists(strName As String, wkbS As Workbook)
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set sh = wbook.Worksheets(strName)
    
    SheetExists = (Err = 0)
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Option Explicit` force explicit declaration of all variables in the module. It is helpful to avoid some coding errors.

***Note:*** The code isn't tested coz of lacking sample data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub pivots()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wBook As Workbook, dataSht As Worksheet
    Dim strName As String, dBook As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, i As Long, LR As Long
    'Clear Contents
    Set dBook = Workbooks("District.xlsm")
    dBook.Activate
    For Each Sht In dBook.Worksheets
        Sht.Cells.ClearContents
    Next Sht
    Set wBook = Workbooks("data.xlsm")
    ' Loop through all sheets in data.xlsm
    For Each Sht In wBook.Worksheets
        ' Check same sheet in District.xlsm
        If SheetExists(Sht.Name, dBook) Then
            Set dataSht = dBook.Sheets(Sht.Name)
            dataSht.Select
            For i = 1 To 9
                Sht.PivotTables("PivotTable" & i).TableRange1.Copy
                LR = dataSht.Range("A" & dataSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                If LR = 1 Then LR = 0
                ' Select the first blank cell in col A
                dataSht.Range("A" & LR + 1).Select
                dataSht.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Next i
        End If
    Next Sht
    MsgBox "done!"
    'Formatting pivot tables for column adjustment
    Workbooks("District.xlsm").Sheets("Northland").UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
'Function to check for same sheet name
Function SheetExists(strName As String, wBook As Workbook)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = wBook.Worksheets(strName)
    SheetExists = (Err = 0)
End Function
```